# How to add a break line to a String AS2

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, line-breaks

I have this String in AS2 and instead of horizontal I need it vertical, however I'm not sure how to add the line break correctly.

var countdown:String = days + " . " + hours + " . " + minutes + " . " + seconds;

I'll appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simply append a newline character to the end of your string like so.

```
var countdown:String = days + " . " + hours + " . " + minutes + " . " + seconds + "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "newline" without quotations to create a line break in strings.

Example:
var countdown:String = days + newline + hours + newline + minutes + newline + seconds;

`\n` does NOT work. I've tried just about every answer and newline was the only one that worked for me. It might be because I'm using Actionscript2 though.